# ImportErrors with Python setuptools.command.sdist

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, importerror

I'm trying to install [Newspaper](http://newspaper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which installs a whole bunch of dependencies using pip. During the installation of a lot of its dependencies, this error is getting raised:

```
ImportError: <module 'setuptools.command.sdist' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools-10.0.1-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/sdist.pyc'> has no '_default_revctrl' attribute
```

Installing without pip works fine, but is quite tedious due to the number of dependencies Newspaper has. Can anyone give me a hand?

Here's the full traceback for one instance of the error:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-auItlo/Pillow/setup.py", line 757, in <module>
        zip_safe=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "<string>", line 15, in replacement_run
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools-10.0.1-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 206, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools-10.0.1-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 290, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools-10.0.1-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 322, in add_defaults
        rcfiles = list(walk_revctrl())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools-10.0.1-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 18, in walk_revctrl
        for item in ep.load()(dirname):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools-10.0.1-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2265, in load
        raise ImportError("%r has no %r attribute" % (entry, attr))
    ImportError: <module 'setuptools.command.sdist' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools-10.0.1-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/sdist.pyc'> has no '_default_revctrl' attribute
```

Comment: Could you try using Python 2.7? It may be that the package doesn't support Python 2.6.

Comment: Trying this now, thanks [edit] That was it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could also be caused by a change in setuptools released today:

https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/320/cannot-upgrade-to-1001

Comment: Wow, nice catch. Using setuptools 9.1 let me install Newspaper for Python 2.6 (although I think there might be other compatibility issues).

Answer (score 0):

running easy_install solved it for me:

```
easy_install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading setuptools with pip can solve this:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```